# Getting the name of the interface itself and not that of the extended class

Tags: class, interface

I am stuck here with a problem in java where I want to call the name of the class,
Here I am having two different cases:

Case #1:

The class/ interface Outputdeclaration is as follows defined:

```
public interface Outputdeclaration extends _ElementA {
```

whereas _ElementA is defined as:

```
public interface _ElementA extends EObject {
```

Here I get "Outputdeclaration" as the name of the contained class when the following code lines are used:

```
for (int i = 0, size = MetaObject.getEAllContainments().size(); i < size; ++i) {

    EClassifier ContainedClass = MetaObject.getEAllContainments().get(i).getEType();

    System.out.println(ContainedClass.getName());

}
```

Case #2:

The class/ interface FloatingPoint is as follows defined:

```
public interface FloatingPoint extends DataTypeA {
```

whereas DataTypeA is defined as:

```
public interface DataTypeA extends _ElementA {
```

and _ElementA is defined as:

```
public interface _ElementA extends EObject {
```

Here I get "DataTypeA" as the name of the contained class when the following code lines are used:

```
for (int i = 0, size = MetaObject.getEAllContainments().size(); i < size; ++i) {

    EClassifier ContainedClass = MetaObject.getEAllContainments().get(i).getEType();

    System.out.println(ContainedClass.getName());

}
```

the first case works pretty well with what I want to get. However the second case is not what I wish, indeed I want to have "FloatingPoint" as the contained class name.

I will be so glad if anyone could help

Comment: What language are you using? Looks like Java

Comment: the language is java